# How to redirect using a view name in Django, class-based views?

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-class-based-views, classname

I have to redirect from one class-based View to another class-based View. I did it by:

```
return redirect('report')
```

but the suggestion was to redirect by View names. I did try this, but it doesn't work.

**views.py:**

```
class UploadView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Reservation.objects.all().delete()
        template = "ReportApp/upload.html"
        return render(request, template)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # try:
        csv_file = request.FILES['file']
        data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
        # setup a stream which is when we loop through each line we are able to handle a data in a stream
        io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)

        next(io_string)
        for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
            _ = Reservation.objects.update_or_create(
                reservation_code=column[0],
                checkin=column[1],
                checkout=column[2],
                flat=column[3],
                city=column[4],
                net_income=column[5],
            )
        # return redirect('report')
        return redirect(ReportView.as_view())

upload_view = UploadView.as_view()


class ReportView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

**urls.py:**

```
from .views import upload_view, report_view, city_commission_view, error_view
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('upload', upload_view, name='upload'),
    path('report', report_view, name='report'),
    path('city_commission', city_commission_view, name='city_commission'),
    path('error', error_view, name='error'),
]
```

any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve and I do not see the code for `class ReportView(View): def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

but perhaps you could try something like this:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

    class ReportView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url_params = self.kwargs
```

and play with that.